# Laravel 10 controller multiple 'Where' clauses in search query returns empty set

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to search the entire row of my database for the user's searchbar input. The code I have returns an empty set:

```
   $posts = Post::where([
            ['title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['intro', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_1_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_1_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_2_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_2_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_3_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_3_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_4_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_4_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_5_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['row_5_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%'],
            ['conclusion', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%']
            ])->get();
```

This is returning a blank space in my search.blade.php. What should the proper query look like?

I need it to say:

```
Search and return the user's input in the title, description, intro, row_1_heading, etc...
```

The query below works but only for the title:

```
$posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

Comment: AND vs OR .. basic knowledge on SQL for filter your data.

Comment: The design looks a bit flawed - anytime you have a numerical index it looks like another table would fit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find posts where any of the fields contain the search term, you should use `orWhere` instead of `where`.

```php
$posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('intro', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_1_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_1_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_2_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_2_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_3_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_3_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_4_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_4_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_5_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('row_5_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('conclusion', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields =['title','description','intro', 'row_1_heading', ..., 'conclusion'];

$posts = Post::query()
              ->where(function($query) use ($fields, $search){    
                foreach($fields as $field){
                   $query->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%') 
                  }
         })->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use `orWhere()` for each condition instead of using only one `where()` Like this :

```
$posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('intro', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
      ....... continue other fields
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You're using the correct syntax. There is nothing wrong with it. The query that you made states that the input must be available in every column of database. Means, if the input is "test", it should be available in title, available in description, available in intro... etc. Which might not be the case.

I think you meant to use `OR` clause in your query. You can do that by using `orWhere()`, you can read more about it here in [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#or-where-clauses).